# If I don't like a quest reward can I pick a different one?

Tags: borderlands-2

Certain Unique quest reward items are really only good if they have certain attributes like special elements. Earlier I got Moxxie's Kiss of Death but I really wanted a Shock one. Is there any way to re-roll the attributes of a quest reward?

Answer (score 7):

Yes in fact! Just quit the game *before* accepting the reward (use Alt-F4 on PC, quitting to the dashboard on consoles, or otherwise end your game without saving). You'll lose a few minute's progress (until the last autosave) but the mission should still be completed (if you can, make sure you trigger a save before checking the quest reward).

This way you can reroll the item, most commonly to change the element. Before you start pulling out your hair, note that some rewards are always of a certain element. Also unless the weapon is guaranteed to have *an* element (Maliwan guns or non-Torgue grenades) it may be very hard to find elemental versions of weapons (particularly *specific* elemental versions) since those parts are just fairly rare, except on grenades and Maliwan guns.

Also note that stat differences will generally be minor. The gun will feature different parts, but certain features like element, bonus crit damage etc make a big difference for some guns; that's when this is handy.

For *most* quests this should leave you at the point where you can just turn in the quests, but you might lose some progress when the turn-in point isn't a person; I'm not sure about those.

Comment: Tested on console but I assume this works on console as well; I know PS3 has a way to quit direct to the menu without saving in-game and I assume the 360 does as well

Comment: I can definitly confirm that you can quit to the dashboard to avoid the auto-save on the Xbox 360. I'll suggest an edit for avoiding auto-save on consoles.