# Is there a way to farm mission items without starting over the whole game?

Tags: borderlands-2

During my first full play of the game, I accepted any mission as soon as it was available then sold the resulting item for a quick profit. Sadly, it wasn't until after completely finishing my first play-through that I finally learned the true value of the majority of one-time-only quest items (Evil Smasher anyone?).

So is there a way to start a new game, quickly get to TVHM to accept level 50 missions? Additionally, could I just accept the quests with my level 50 char in a new game, or will the mission just scale to the host level?

Comment: Ack - what about the Evil Smasher? I just sold that!

Comment: @Iszi [This glitch...](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Evil_Smasher#Glitch)

Comment: @Iszi there's an [extremely overpowered exploit for it](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Evil_Smasher#Glitch)

Comment: @BenBrocka Same link but I like your wording better

Comment: Accept the quest, complete it, turn it in, if you don't like the reward alt+f4/xbox guide button/ps button out of the game so it doesn't save, repeat untill satisfied with the reward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only get a quest reward once per playthrough per character. This means there's only one chance for a level 50 Evil Smasher. If you join someone else's game and re-complete a mission, you will not get rewards for that mission again.

> So is there a way to start a new game, quickly get to TVHM to accept level 50 missions?

No, not without save file editing. And my limited attempts at messing with Gibbed's editor have been unsuccessful. And a playthrough with a hacked level 50 character from start to completing THVM will still take several hours.

> Additionally, could I just accept the quests with my level 50 char in a new game, or will the mission just scale to the host level?

Missions are complicated. It seems to find a way to always give you the lowest possible quest reward; if you've already taken the mission, it seems to give you the item at the level you took that mission, ignoring the host's mission level. I'm not 100% sure about that though, confirmation would be nice.

Comment: So in short I have to grind a new character to level 50? Is there a way to save-scum and turn in quests more than once so I only have to grind once?

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk not 100% sure what you mean by grinding, you mean [a trick like this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96418/if-i-dont-like-a-quest-reward-can-i-pick-a-different-one)?

Comment: That would be perfect. And by grind I besically mean that I only want to get _one_ character to 50 and do the quests _once_. Not get multiple chars to 50 if the item I DO get isn't what I wanted.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk with the exception of picking the wrong reward (when there are 2 choices) or the element being wrong, there's not too much variation between rewards. I think most Unique rewards have mostly predefined parts, element being the most significant variation (if possible)

Comment: The only weapons I found useful for those quests with unique weps were The Evil Smasher (for the insane glitch) and Rubi (for insane health regen).

Comment: The weapon that justifies save-scamming the most is The Fibber. It comes with 3 barrels, of which only one is uber-OP. So there's only 33% chance to get a somewhat useful one, not mentioning a good element (none) and best of other parts. Can't find the forum post now :(

Comment: @OrcJMR forgot about the Fibber. There's at least one combo of that which works really well with Gaige, especially with a Shock one

Comment: As opposed to leveling up a new character to level 50, the other option would be to find someone who has the item and just dupe it, or use gibbed's.

Answer (score 0):

If you complete the game, there should be a harder mode. Play through in that one to the same quest, you just wont have access to teleportation. either way, if you start a new game on the easier difficulty or the harder, you have to play through til you reach the mission.